# Turning on network-manager terminates ssh

Tags: ssh, hotspot, pi-zero-w-2, networkmanager

I am new to this whole thing. I am trying to setup a hotspot on my pi zero 2 w and installed the pi-OS lite legacy 32 bit using the pi imager and setup the wifi connection and ssh thingy from there. Initially I am able to ssh into it and download packages. but when i follow this [guide](https://www.raspberrypi.com/tutorials/host-a-hotel-wifi-hotspot/)
it wants me to enable networkmanager and when i enable it using sudo raspi-config >> advanced >> network >> and i switch from dhcpcd to networkmanager my connection terminates and my zero 2 w is not seen in the list of connected devices in my router and i cannot ssh in nor can i ping it... i tried scanning the whole network and still nope.
P.s. i am running a headless set up.. and i dont have a keyboard, and monitor to do it using the gui.
sorry for my bad grammar and if i sound rude i didn't mean too

Comment: Try writing in English - using sentences and paragraphs and explain **what YOU did**.

Comment: sorry i'll try.... umm soo what i did i typed sudo raspi-config i went to advanced and then network settings i think then i clicked on network manager and suddenly the ssh connection terminats and its not on my lan network anymore

Answer (score 0):

If you create a hotspot (which is what the tutorial describes) - you (if you are lucky and do it correctly) will **have a Hotspot**.

You could connect to this Hotspot (which by definition means you can no longer use as a WiFi client).

Switching to `NetworkManager` has nothing to do with a Hotspot (although it can create one).

If you just switched to `NetworkManager` it would be in client mode (although you would have to create a WiFi connection).

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/139795/8697

NOTE attempting to do this over a `ssh` connection is difficult (if not impossible) - you need a keyboard and monitor.

NOTE2 the tutorial requires 2 WiFi devices - do you have a 2nd, if so explain how it is configured.

Comment: when i try nmcli it says error networkmanager not active

Comment: It is far from clear what you have done. If "connection terminates" how are you doing anythin?

Comment: when i initially set up the pi using the pi imager - i gave the wifi credentials and enabled ssh then after pi imager is done writing - i put the sd card into the pi zero 2 w and then connected it to a power source - then i ssh into the pi using my laptop - when i try to switch to network manager the ssh terminates and the pi is nowhere to be seen on my wifi network

Comment: i didnt read the wifi adapter part.. oops sorry my bad.. - but still how can i set up a hotspot in a headless setup??

Comment: Which part of "you need a keyboard and monitor" don't you understand? You simply can't change networking while using it.